# for loop 5-6 times slower than foreach loop in HtmlAgility Pack

Tags: html-agility-pack

I test 2 loops with the same values and code:
1) For loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MyGlobals.check1Count; i++)
{
addToMyGlobals(root2.SelectNodes(strXPath)[i].OuterHtml.Trim(), XPathArrayIndex);
}
```

2) Foreach loop:

```
        foreach (HtmlNode link1 in root2.SelectNodes(strXPath))
        {
          addToMyGlobals(link1.OuterHtml.Trim(), XPathArrayIndex);
        }
```

And the results is that 'Foreach loop' is 5-6 times faster than the 'For Loop'. Why is that, what is happening, can somebody gives explanation about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for loop, you are executing the expensive SelectNodes() method on every iteration of the loop.  The foreach loop only does this once.

Comment: Why in foreach loop does it only once? On each iteration it goes into root2.SelectNodes(strXPath) to take the value (.OuterHtml property)

Comment: The first time it evaluates SelectNodes() to build a list of nodes, then it iterates through that list.  It does not re-evaluate SelectNodes() each time.  You could do the same thing with the for loop by evaluating SelectNodes() before the loop starts and storing its results in a list that is used within the loop.